# Usage of delta operator

Tags: notation, conventions, differentiation

So I've always thought that "$\Delta$" when applied to an n-tuple or scalar was the change of that n-tuple or scalar relative to a previous state in time and proportional to the amount of time or $\Delta \bf{x}=\frac{\bf{x_u}-\bf{x_i}}{t_u-t_i}$ so I always wrote the acceleration of a mass as $\Delta^2 M_p$ but now I am unsure whether this is in fact correct. My question is: What are all of the different ways Delta can be used as well as am I using it correctly?

Comment: The proposed duplicate doesn't actually address the question as the OP is interested in the distinction between $\Delta$ meaning "difference of" and $\Delta = \nabla^2$. Of course, I generaly don't write $\Delta$ when I mean $\nabla^2$, but that is a matter of preference.

Comment: That said, llama, *please* read the hove-over text when picking tags. For instance the one about [mathematical-physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/mathematical-physics/info) says *"DO NOT USE THIS TAG just because your question involves math!"*.

Comment: @dmckee I did and from what I understood of its blurry in meaning hover-text, this question is about a part of maths that is a fundamental basis for physics... tell me how you think it was supposed to be interpretted if you do not agree (which you clearly don't).

Comment: Mathematical physics is *not* about the math you need to do physics, it is about the mathematical structure of physics which is a deeper and more difficult thing by a long way. You're asking about the meaning of a notation which is certainly not *"the mathematically rigorous study of the foundations of physics"*.

Comment: @dmckee ahh okay thanks. Would maths be a better/more fitting place for this question then?

Comment: I'm not clear on the scope of [math.se], so I am hesitant to recommend ask this there. Check out their tour and and [faq] question on their meta.